# Is there a way to write below piece of code in java 8 format?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, purely-functional

I am writing a piece of code for creating partition key for a DDB table.
I have long name in dotted format which can have as many names as possible seperated by "."

e.g. qw.er.ty.ui

I want the below method to return the subname of the above name as "SUBNAME_qwer". i.e "SUBNAME_" + firstname + secondname.
Where first name is the string before the first dot in the long name.
and second name is the string after the first dot and before the second dot.

I don't want to make any changes to behaviour of the code but want to write it in JAVA 8 way.
Is it possible?

Snippet 1:

```
    //name is a dotted format hierarchical name. e.g. n.x.y.c
    String getFirstTwoSubNames(final String name) {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("can't be null");
        }
        if (name.contains(".")) {
            String[] subNames = name.split("\\.");
            String firstTwoSubNames = subNames[0] + subNames[1];
            return String.join("_", "SUBNAME", firstTwoSubNames);

        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid format");
        }
    }
```

Update 1:
Sorry for writing my question so poorly. I am new to JAVA 8 and stack overflow.
The ask here is to remove the imperative coding and adopt functional coding style with JAVA 8.
So far with the help of *@Alex Rudenko's* answer I am able to convert the above code to functional JAVA 8-y code as follows:

Snippet 2:

```
 String getFirstTwoSubNames(final String name) {
       return "SUBNAME_" + Arrays.stream(Optional.ofNullable(name)
                    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new)
                    .split("\\."))
                    .limit(2)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
    }
```

**As you can see I am missing the logic of throwing invalid exception from the code snippet 1. I wish to include this in code snippet 2 in functional way.** Hope this brings more clarity to my question.

Comment: What is wrong with this current code? Why does it need to be re-written? You can probably do it as an Optional chain but I doubt it's going to be an improvement.

Comment: What do you imagine the result would look like?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis given the logic, it seems that `n.x.y.c` will be transformed into `SUBNAME_nx`

Comment: `String.join(…)` is already a Java 8 method. Though, its use is pointless here, as `"SUBNAME_" + subNames[0] + subNames[1]` is simpler. You can replace `if (name == null) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("can't be null"); }` with [`requireNonNull(name, "can't be null");`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-) Further, instead of a `name.contains(".")` pre-check, you can simply add a `if(subNames.length == 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid format");` after the `String[] subNames = name.split("\\.");`

Answer (score 1):

A "Java 8"-like solution could be using `Stream.limit` to pick up only 2 sub-names and `Collectors.joining("")`.

The check `name.contains(".")` may be removed, it can be defined after splitting the input string.

```java
String getFirstTwoSubNames(final String name) {
    if (name == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("can't be null");
    }
    String[] subNames = name.split("\\.");
    if (subNames.length < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid format");
    }
    return "SUBNAME_" + Arrays.stream(subNames).limit(2).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

---

**Update**

The updated code snippet #2  may be refactored to separate validation code into separate method, so that `getFirstTwoSubnames` use only valid name:

```java
static String validName(String name) {
    return Stream.of(Optional.ofNullable(name).orElseThrow(NullNameException::new))
                 .filter(name -> name.contains("."))
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElseThrow(MinSubnamesException::new);
}

static String getFirstTwoSubNames(final String name) {
    return "SUBNAME_" + Arrays.stream(validName(name).split("\\."))
                              .limit(2)
                              .collect(Collectors.joining());
}

//--------
// customized exceptions
class NullNameException extends NullPointerException {
    public NullNameException() {
        super("Name cannot be null");
    }
}

class MinSubnamesException extends IllegalArgumentException {
    public MinSubnamesException() {
        super("A name must contain at least two sub-names separated with dot `.`");
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks *barely* Java8-y. It's all the imperative shell with just a tiny bit turned into a more functional style.

Comment: Do you have the feeling that `Arrays.stream(subNames).limit(2).collect(Collectors.joining(""))` is an improvement over `subNames[0] + subNames[1]`?

Comment: @Holger, I don't have such a feeling :)